# How does one list "full time and part time" on a resume?

Tags: resume, internship

I was offered an internship many years back which turned into part-time work... in which I resumed full time work. Now, I'm working part-time again.

I do full time work during the summers, so I'm 4 months full, 8 months part-time.

This means I have many periods where my work hours vary - how do you list this on a resume?

Comment: It's probably better just to describe the work you're doing and what you're accomplishing. Is your 'full time' really 'full time', or do you spend 3 hours a day on stuff that no employer would notice anyway?  Sometimes a lower hour workweek isn't actually half as productive, you find that when you are working you're focused, and when you're not you have time to reflect on what you should be doing when you are.

Comment: @MeredithPoor I think it's a bit assumptions to say that. I work in software engineering -- so I was creating and developing software around the clock. During part-time, I'm more in bug fixing mode than architecting mode.

Comment: Some software work is 'all out' - I've done plenty of that.  Some occurs at a more measured pace, and you have time to think about what you're doing next. Hours != Product. One saying I used to hear but don't any more is that you can't employ 9 women to make a baby in 1 month. One's understanding of the problem they're trying to solve takes a certain amount of time to form, and it occurs somewhat independently of hours worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For positions that weren't 100% full-time, add a note at the end of the description of the position:

> (This position was held part-time.)
>
> (This position was held full- and part-time.)

Your situation isn't unusual, and anyone wanting additional details will ask.